# Need help solving SQL constraint violation

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am unable to solve this error.  `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'ordered_songs.UK_q73sm6y7ob1asdtqty7nxbj2j'`

I have a many to many relationship annotation with Order and Song, which points to collection type elements.  I can successfully add one order, but after that my app breaks when trying to add a second order, and I cannot seem to figure out why.  It looks as though order id is not being incremented when it's called in the controller.

Here is my Order POJO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "ord")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ordered_songs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "song_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Song> orderedSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
    private String status;
    private Date date;
    @Embedded
    private MailingAddress mailingAddress;
}
```

The second POJO is

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Song {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String artist;
    private String genre;
    private String format;
    private double price;
    private String imageUrl;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "orderedSongs")
    @ElementCollection
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
//  private Order order;
}
```

Here is my controller

```
    @PostMapping("/mailing")
    public ModelAndView saveMailingAddress(@RequestParam("street") String street,
            @RequestParam("city") String city,
            @RequestParam("state") String state,
            @RequestParam("zip") int zip,
            ModelMap model) {
        Customer c=(Customer) model.get("customer");
        MailingAddress ma=new MailingAddress();
        ma.setStreet(street);
        ma.setCity(city);
        ma.setState(state);
        ma.setZip(zip);
        Order o=new Order();
        
        o.setStatus("ordered");
        o.setDate(new Date());
        c.getOrders().add(o);       
        o.setCustomer(c);
        o.setMailingAddress(ma);
        
        
        Order o1 = orderDao.save(o);
        
        System.out.println("first msg b4 for loop");
        for(Song s: cs.getSongs()) {
            System.out.println("b4 add to o1");
            o1.getOrderedSongs().add(s);
            System.out.println("b4 save");
            songDao.save(s);
            System.out.println("after save");
        }
        System.out.println("after loop");
        cs.removeAll();
        return new ModelAndView("success");     
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What database are you using? I would probably look for problem here "@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)"

Comment: using MySQL, but unable to see what the issue is with GenrationType.IDENTITY

Comment: Why is Song @Embeddable? It should be an @Entity.